# Jbpm console3.3.1 on jboss web server3.0.0 beta-1

Tags: java, jboss, console, jbpm, jboss-web

I've deployed jbpm-console on jboss-web successfully, but now I'm getting the following error:

```
**2010-01-26 20:59:21,969 嚴重的   [facelets.compiler] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Loading Library: vfszip:/E:/app/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-0125-zip/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-1/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jsf-impl.jar/com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib/ui.taglib.xml: java.io.IOException: Error parsing [vfszip:/E:/app/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-0125-zip/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-1/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jsf-impl.jar/com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib/ui.taglib.xml]:** 
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:410)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:431)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:87)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:104)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:218)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:149)
    at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:100)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:517)
    at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:336)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:479)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:559)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:93)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:366)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:872)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [vfszip:/E:/app/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-0125-zip/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-1/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jsf-impl.jar/com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib/ui.taglib.xml@42,31]
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.error(TagLibraryConfig.java:376)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:407)
    ... 34 more

**Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "facelet-taglib", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    ... 53 more**
```

I guess "DTD" in `ui.taglib.xml` has something wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Anything particular line 42 column 31 in `E:/app/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-0125-zip/jboss-web-3.0.0-beta-1/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jsf-libs/jsf-impl.jar/com/sun/faces/metadata/taglib/ui.taglib.xml`?

Comment: Nice to see you again.
You mean this?
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "facelet-taglib", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
 at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
 ... 53 more